# Outlier removal in pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've recently been doing some NASA data analysis on my own, and I have recently been stuck.

Obviously, with real data, there is a margin of error. (just look at my unfiltered data here! https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcXSS.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XP9N.png)

I am trying to find a way to filter out the outliers logically. For example, if you look in my code, you will see where I experimented a bit:

```
indx = np.abs(rate) < outlierRemovalRate
clean_rate = rate[indx]
clean_time = time[indx]
```

When I ran this, I got this error message:

> File "C:\Users\Ken Preiser\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook.py", line 1439, in safezip
>       raise ValueError(_safezip_msg % (Nx, i + 1, len(arg)))
>   ValueError: In safezip, len(args[0])=29965 but len(args[1])=29972

Obviously, there is some problem where some parts of the outliers are being filtered, but others are not (29972 is the number of data points unfiltered, and 29965 is the number of data points after filtering).

I'll post my whole code below. If anyone can help me with this method of outlier removal or suggest/write another one, I would appreciate it a bunch!! :D Thanks!

```
import os
import pyfits as fits
import numpy as np
import pylab
import random
import scipy.optimize
import scipy.signal


from numpy import arange
from matplotlib import pyplot
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from collections import OrderedDict

rate = np.sum(data['RATE'][:,:4], axis=1)

#outlier removal
indx = np.abs(rate) < outlierRemovalRate
clean_rate = rate[indx]
clean_time = time[indx]

error = data.field('ERROR')
error = np.sqrt(np.sum(data['ERROR'][:,:4]**2, axis=1))

print clean_rate.size,(" rate")
print clean_time.size,(" time")

fig = pylab.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

pylab.show()
```

Comment: It is also not clear what you question is.  Can you reduce this to the _minimal_ amount of code (and preferably with synthetic data) to show the problem?

Comment: @tcaswell Edited out a bunch. Tell me if that makes it easier to read.

Comment: What is the type of `data`? I don't see why that should be going through cbook at all.

Comment: umm, is that important? haha

Answer (score -2, accepted):

At first you should fix your imports, you import some things multiple times:

matplotlib.pyplot, numpy and scipy are included in pylab

Second:

Your mistake is clearly in the `error`, you don't cut away the values over the threshold there.